# How do you limit a resque queue to a single worker and guarantee the job processes using that worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have a set of devices (say device 1-10) and each need to be treated synchronously. For each one generated I setup a new queue with 1 worker and then enqueue_to the specific device_#{num} queue. However, these jobs are getting processed by other workers versus the worker under the queue they are assigned to (Which breaks the attempted synchronous behavior).

```
  def self.run_queue(queue_name, root_path, env, count = 1)
    pid_name = "#{queue_name}"
    pid_file = "#{root_path}/tmp/pids/#{pid_name}.pid"
    cmd = ["RAILS_ENV=#{env}",
           "rake resque:work QUEUE=#{pid_name}",
           "COUNT=#{count} BACKGROUND=yes",
           "PIDFILE=#{pid_file}",
           ">> #{root_path}/log/#{pid_name}.log"].join(' ')
    %x(#{cmd}) unless is_pid_running("#{pid_name}")
  end
```

More explanation:

the root queue runs many different jobs.  This is setup with multiple workers.  However, there are some jobs that require device testing.  These individual jobs can connect to a device and run the necessary tests.  We can only run 1 job at a time against an individual device.  The job connects, runs the tests, checks the logs, dumps the logs, and then disconnects.  When this is done the next job for that particular device's queue can run.

Right now I have these individual device queues set up with 1 worker (COUNT=1).  This is an attempt to force the device queue to run "synchronously" thus guaranteeing that a device only has 1 job testing it at a time...

This isn't working out as the jobs in the device queue are using workers designated to the root queue.

Comment: how are you starting resque also explain this line in detail if possible `hese jobs are getting processed by other workers versus the worker under the queue they are assigned to`

Comment: I've updated the question with how I start the individual queues.  Note that I am setting this queue up with 1 worker (default).  The issue is that when I submit a job to that particular queue (ex "dynamic_queue_1") the job processes on any available worker rather than waiting on the one for the queue to complete.  Again, trying to make these individual queues process synchronously.

Comment: It hard to understand but here what I understood correct me if I'm wrong that you started one worker and you submit a job say `A`(under processing) and then you submit another job to dynamic_queue_1 say `B` now you want the resque to process the job `B` only when job `A` is done is that correct. If that is what you want I don`t thing resque allow you do that You have to achieve it in some other ways . I can answer that but I need to know whether my understanding is clear with respect to your post

Comment: Added more info to the question